# highlighting error lines within codemirror textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I have textarea consisting C code. I want to highlight lines onClick based on few keywords. I am storing the line in variable and checking each line with keyword.

```
$('#error').click(
        function() {
            var editor= $("textarea[id='c-code']");
            var lines = editor.val().split('\n');
            editor.val(" ");
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i].contains("flag")) {
                    var value = '<mark>'
                            + lines[i] + '</mark>';
             editor.append(value );
            editor.append('\n');
                }
            }
        });
```

However its not working. Here is my jsfiddle [testfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kmy5oqe/20/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you're running into is that Codemirror manages the textArea for you, so you need to get and set the textArea with the CodeMirror functions `getValue()` and `setValue( val )`.

```
var cEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("c-code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-csrc",
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
    lint: true
  });

$('#error').click(
  function () {
  var lines = cEditor.getValue().split('\n');
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (0 < lines[i].indexOf("flag")) {
      lines[i] = '<mark>' + lines[i] + '</mark>\n';
    }
  }
  cEditor.setValue(lines.join('\n'));
});
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:  Per comment, tweaking the script to highlight an entire line in color.**

To highlight the entire line in color, the following links help provide guidance:  [CodeMirror markText is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048167) and https://github.com/perak/codemirror/issues/24.  Using this guidance, the code above can be modified to...

```
var cEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("c-code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-csrc",
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
    lint: true
  });

$('#error').click(
  function () {
  var lines = cEditor.getValue().split('\n');
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (0 < lines[i].indexOf("flag")) {
      cEditor.getDoc().markText({line:i,ch:0},{line:i,ch:lines[i].length},{css: "background-color: yellow"});
    }
  }
});
```

...and now the lines with the word `flag` will have a background in yellow.

Comment: yes you are right! thank you so much, its working :) However i am unable change the color of line. its adding <mark> as text in the textarea.

Comment: @ariana, See Edit above, with update to the code to exemplify using CodeMirror to highlight rows in yellow.